# How to use 'OR' operator in an 'if' condition with '=' in plsql?

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql

There are two if statements in my pl sql code where I am doing the same action. I tried to combine the two if statements with 'OR' condition. But it fails. If I check two conditions separately as in below it works as expected.

```
   IF(rec_.invoice_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
      IF (Tax_API.Tax_Items_Taxable_Exist(rec_.company, Tax_Source_API.DB_INVOICE, TO_CHAR(rec_.invoice_id), TO_CHAR(rec_.item_id), '*', '*', '*') = 'TRUE')THEN 
         type   := 'A';
      END IF;
   ELSE 
      IF(Report_Type_API.Is_Taxable_Db(rec_.company, rec_.report_code, rec_.account_date)='TRUE') THEN 
         type   := 'A';
      END IF;
   END IF;
```

If I combine two if statements with a 'OR' condition as below, why does not it work?

```
IF ((Tax_API.Tax_Items_Taxable_Exist(rec_.company, Tax_Source_API.DB_INVOICE, TO_CHAR(rec_.invoice_id), TO_CHAR(rec_.item_id), '*', '*', '*') = 'TRUE') OR (Report_Type_API.Is_Taxable_Db(rec_.company, rec_.report_code, rec_.account_date)='TRUE'))THEN
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```
  IF     rec_.invoice_id IS NOT NULL
     AND (   tax_api.tax_items_taxable_exist (rec_.company,
                                              tax_source_api.db_invoice,
                                              TO_CHAR (rec_.invoice_id),
                                              TO_CHAR (rec_.item_id),
                                              '*',
                                              '*',
                                              '*') = 'TRUE'
          OR report_type_api.is_taxable_db (rec_.company,
                                            rec_.report_code,
                                            rec_.account_date) =
             'TRUE')
  THEN
     TYPE := 'A';
  END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to include the tests for the `NULL` state of `rec_.invoice_id` on both sides of the `OR` condition:

```sql
IF (   rec_.invoice_id IS NOT NULL
   AND Tax_API.Tax_Items_Taxable_Exist(
         rec_.company,
         Tax_Source_API.DB_INVOICE,
         TO_CHAR(rec_.invoice_id),
         TO_CHAR(rec_.item_id),
         '*',
         '*',
         '*'
       ) = 'TRUE'
   )
OR (   rec_.invoice_id IS NULL
   AND Report_Type_API.Is_Taxable_Db(
         rec_.company,
         rec_.report_code,
         rec_.account_date
       ) = 'TRUE'
   )
THEN 
   type   := 'A';
END IF;
```